# Keras Dot Axes questions

Tags: keras, axes

I am trying to use Keras `Dot` and have the following errors.
Could you explain what I am doing wrong?

```py
x1 = Input(shape=(2,4))
x2 = Input(shape=(4,))
y1 = dot([x1,x2], axes = (2,1))
modelA = Model(inputs=[x1, x2], outputs=y1)

a1 = np.arange(16).reshape(2,2,4)
a2 = np.array( [1,2,3,4] )

modelA.predict([a1,a2])

---->
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_40 to have shape (None, 4) but 
got array with shape (4, 1)
```

Comment: The shape of input tensors are not compatible for computing the dot product. `x1` is a tensor of shape `(None, 2, 4)` and `x2` is a tensor of shape `(None, 4)` (both `None` refers to batch dimension). So how do you want to compute the dot product between these two tensors? Even if you could, the `a2` is a tensor of shape `(4,1)` and therefore is not compatible with the `x2` specified shape; that's what the error is trying to convey.

Comment: Thanks. for example  a1 =  [[[ 0  1  2  3]  [ 4  5  6  7]] [[ 8  9 10 11] [12 13 14 15]]] and a2 = [1,2,3,4] and i want to get [ [20,60] [ 100,140]]. 20 comes from dot product of [0 1 2 3] and [1 2 3 4[, 60 comes from dot product of [4 5 6 7] and [1 2 3 4]. Similary 100, 140 come from dot product of [8 9 10 11] , [12 13 14 15] with [1 2 3 4], respectively.

Comment: Interestingly enough, an undocumented feature allows to set negative integer as axes parameter of Dot layer and the model then trains the dimensionality of axes on their own during its compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Keras, too. And the following is what I figured out after playing around with the Dot operation.

Firstly, the `shape` parameter of Input layer is NOT including the batch size. In your code, `x2 = Input(shape=(4,))`, so x2 is expecting the input data to be (None, 4), (None refers to batch size), but a2 is `np.array([1,2,3,4])`, the shape is (1, 4), hence the error message.
To get rid of the error you need to add the batch_size dimension to a2.

But then there is another problem, according to the doc of Dot, I think x1 and x2 should have the same batch size:

> if applied to a list of two tensors a and b of shape (batch_size, n), the output will be a tensor of shape (batch_size, 1) where each entry i will be the dot product between a[i] and b[i].

So I manually match the batch size of a1 and a2, and the batch size of a1 is 2, so a2 needs to be `np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])`

Now you can have your desire result:

`[[ 20.  60.]
 [100. 140.]]`

A few more words for beginners like me, the shape of x1 is (batch_size, 2, 4), the shape of x2 is (batch_size, 4), it seems that they are not compatible. Now is when the 'axes' parameter comes into play. In OP's code, `axes=(2,1)` means to dot x1's 3rd axis (0-indexed, it's the axis with the length of 4),  with x2's 2nd axis(also the length is 4). So it will be [0,1,2,3]dot[1,2,3,4]=20, [4,5,6,7]dot[1,2,3,4]=60 ...